# How do I display data from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I receive an error when I try to print the data, the prediction and then the difference (please see the last three lines of code). I am not understanding why. I am trying to print out a DataFrame. I am sure that I am missing something very simple. My goal is just to show the predicted values, the actuals values and the differences and create a DataFrame from this data and then print it out. Maybe there is a simpler way of doing this or possibly I am attempting to create a DataFrame using data in an incorrect form possibly.
I know that I turned `y_test` from a DataFrame into a series. `preds` is an nparray and  `y_test - preds` is a Series. I am not sure why the data must be one dimensional to use to create a dataFrame.

Here is the error:

```
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2bdd5734b3fe> in <module>
     43 
     44 #my_dict = { 'True count lost': y_test,'Prediction': preds,'Error': y_test - preds}
---> 45 df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'True count lost': y_test,'Prediction': preds,'Error': y_test - preds})
     46 
     47 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in _sanitize_ndim(result, data, dtype, index, allow_2d)
    625             if allow_2d:
    626                 return result
--> 627             raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    628         if is_object_dtype(dtype) and isinstance(dtype, ExtensionDtype):
    629             # i.e. PandasDtype("O")

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Here is the code:

```
# Data Manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# DataViz
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Modeling
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor



#create a dtaframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,3,3,4,5,8,10,9,11,12],'y': [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,16,17]}) 

#Plot the original data points 
plt.plot(df.x, df.y, 'bo', label="y-original")


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['x']],df[['y']], test_size= 0.3, random_state=12)


print(f'XTrain yTrain shapes: {x_train.shape, y_train.shape}  \n XTest  yTest shapes: {x_test.shape, y_test.shape}')

y_test = y_test.iloc[:,0]



# Instance and fit
knn_model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5).fit(x_train, y_train)

# Score
score_knn = knn_model.score(x_test, y_test)
print(f"The score is {score_knn}")


# Predictions--Use the test data to evlauate the model's performance
preds = knn_model.predict(x_test)
preds


df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'True count lost': y_test,'Prediction': preds,'Error': y_test - preds})
                            
                            

print(df2)
```

Comment: You receive an error? What error? You haven't shown us the error. How would you feel about debugging the code if it just said "there's been an error" and didn't tell you anything else? ***If you get an error, include it in the question, in full.***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks. I included the full error message. The problem is the last three lines of code.  I want to print a chart with actual value, predicted value and then the difference. Perhaps there is a better or easier way to do this?